# .Net Core fast alloc and zero initialise memory (cross-platform solution)

Tags: memory-management, .net-core

Is there a fast way to allocate and zero initialise a large block of memory using .Net Core?

Looking for a solution that works on both Windows and Linux platforms.

It seems the fastest method on Windows is to call kernel32 HeapAlloc function via PInvoke, this allocates and zeros a 1GB block of memory in less than 2 milliseconds.

However, I haven't found a way to achieve similar results on Linux whilst only using .Net Core.

I've tried the `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` method which does not zero the memory, and then zeroing the memory using Marshal.Copy to copy an array of zero bytes into the memory, but this gives poor performance i.e. 800 milliseconds compared to the 2 milliseconds above.

For my application the allocation and zeroing needs to be done in less than 10 milliseconds.

Does .Net Core provide a cross platform API that would give similar performance as Windows HeapAlloc or something like the C function `calloc`?

Test code below:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MemoryApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int sizeBytes = 1_000_000_000;

            Console.WriteLine($"Allocating memory of size: {sizeBytes} bytes.");

            const int totalAttempts = 20;

            for (int i = 0; i < totalAttempts; i++)
            {
                var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                var allocatedMemory = new AllocatedMemory(sizeBytes);

                stopwatch.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine($"Allocated memory in {stopwatch.ElapsedTicks} ticks ({stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds).");

                allocatedMemory.Dispose();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public unsafe class AllocatedMemory : IDisposable
    {
        public byte* MemoryAddress { get; }

#if USE_WINDOWS_HEAP
        private IntPtr _heapPtr;
#else
        private IntPtr _memoryPtr;
#endif

        public AllocatedMemory(int sizeInBytes)
        {
#if USE_WINDOWS_HEAP
            var heapFlags = HeapFlags.HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS | HeapFlags.HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY;

            _heapPtr = Heap.HeapCreate(heapFlags, 0, 0);
            MemoryAddress = (byte*)Heap.HeapAlloc(_heapPtr, heapFlags, (uint)sizeInBytes);
#else
            // Memory allocated but not zeroed
            _memoryPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr)sizeInBytes);

            // Zero the memory
            Marshal.Copy(new byte[sizeInBytes], 0, _memoryPtr, sizeInBytes);
            MemoryAddress = (byte*)_memoryPtr;
#endif
        }

        ~AllocatedMemory()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (MemoryAddress != null)
                {
#if USE_WINDOWS_HEAP
                    Heap.HeapDestroy(_heapPtr);
#else
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_memoryPtr);
#endif
                }
            }
        }
    }

#if USE_WINDOWS_HEAP
    public class Heap
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr HeapCreate(HeapFlags flOptions, uint dwInitialsize, uint dwMaximumSize);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr HeapAlloc(IntPtr hHeap, HeapFlags dwFlags, uint dwSize);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool HeapDestroy(IntPtr hHeap);
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum HeapFlags
    {
        HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE = 0x1,
        HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS = 0x4,
        HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY = 0x8
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Is it that `new` is slow on Linux, or do you need to marshal the buffer to native?

Comment: Thanks @500-InternalServerError, the application uses a lot of unsafe code with pointers for high performance, so the AllocatedMemory object needs to provide a `byte*` pointer to the caller hence the MemoryAddress public property.  I'm not sure using `new` would be relevant in this case? Do you mean declare an array of bytes like `new byte[sizeInBytes]`?

Answer (score 0):

In C# 7, .Net has introduced new constructs to work with memory which include Span and Memory

Span is defined as a ref struct, limited to allocation only on the Stack, i.e. reduces some potential use cases such as storing it as a field in a class. But you can work around these by using another type Memory